# Wierd faculty question. Determine minimum number of questions to be answered

Tags: python

I am writing an internal company assessment in Hackerrank in Python. I got question as below. this is not exact question, as I could not copy from HackerRank page.

You have a question paper with 'n' questions. The marks for each question are predefined. If a question has answer value 1, you get +1 score, if it is 0 you get -1 score for that question. If you answer 'k' number of questions, your friend has to answer 'n-k' questions.

Determine the value of k so that your score is greater than your friends score.

**Sample Case:**

Predefined marks for 10 questions : {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1}

you have to answer atleast 6 questions so that your score is higher than your friend.

I have written the below code with sample input. can you please help me to **optimize** it so that execution is completed in 10 sec?

```
import numpy as np

arr= np.random.randint(0,2,500000)
n=len(arr)
#print(n)
#print(arr)
for m,x in enumerate(arr):
    k=n-m
    #print("m:", end=" ")
    #print(m)
    arr_k = arr[m:]
    arr_m = arr[:m]
    c1m = np.sum(arr_m == 1)
    c0m = np.sum(arr_m == 0)
    m_score = c1m - c0m
    c1k = np.sum(arr_k == 1)
    c0k = np.sum(arr_k == 0)
    k_score = c1k - c0k
    #print(m_score)
    #print(k_score)
    if m_score > k_score:
        print("Questions to be answered:", end=" ")
        print(m_score)
        break
```

the value of arr is provided in test case in hackerrank. Every time we get different values. i have just put here to test my code.

Comment: You have to answer first n questions, right?

Comment: I think it's not a matter of optimizing the code but providing you with a better algorithm.  Your current algorithm is O(n^2), This could probably need to be reduced to O(n) or at most O(n*log(n)), where n is the length of arr.  But, seeing if coders can create good algorithms is a big part of Hackerrank questions which defeats the purpose if answers are provided by others in an open forum.

Comment: Hint: There is a simple O(n) algorithm.

Comment: @DarrylG , yes you are right. I do not need full answer, any hints to improve my code so that in any case execution should be completed in 10 sec. Thanku for the hint. i will try to improve my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderGolys, you an answer any number of questions and your friend should answer remaining questions. we need find how many question you should answer so that your score is more than your friend.

Comment: Your code is O(n^2) since due to performing a sum over the array inside a for loop.  The sum is O(n) and the for loop is O(n), so together this is O(n^2).  You need to change to an algorithm where computing your score is O(1) and computing your friend's score is O(1).  This way the overall complexity is O(n).   Hint would be to do a google search for related problems.

Comment: @DarrylG, Thanku for the suggestion. I have modified logic now most of the time program executes within 10 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is close, it just needs a slight (thought major impact) tweak as follows to create code which is O(n):

```
import numpy as np

arr= np.random.randint(0,2,100000)
arr[arr==0] = -1
n_score = np.sum(arr)
print("n_score:",n_score)
m_score = 0    # will use for running total
for m,x in enumerate(arr):
    #m_score = np.sum(arr[:m+1])  # replace this which is O(n)
    m_score += arr[m]             # with this which is O(1) (popular code pattern)
    k_score = n_score - m_score
    if m_score > k_score:
        print("Questions to be answered:", end=" ")
        print(m+1)
        break
```

Note: Although no effect on runtime or output, I would suggest for clarity use:

```
print(f"Questions to be answered: {m+1}")
```

Rather than:

```
print("Questions to be answered:", end=" ")
print(m+1)
```

Comment: @DarryIG, Thanku so much. i could not think of this. reg print message : sure i will follow your suggestion. it seems more clear.

Comment: @Sailaja--glad to help.  I probably only thought of this since I've seen this trick many times before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated version of my code. any suggestions are welcome.

```
import numpy as np

arr= np.random.randint(0,2,100000)
arr[arr==0] = -1
n_score = np.sum(arr)
print("n_score:",n_score)
for m,x in enumerate(arr):
    m_score = np.sum(arr[:m+1])
    k_score = n_score - m_score
    if m_score > k_score:
        print("Questions to be answered:", end=" ")
        print(m+1)
        break
```

Comment: @Salialaja--this may pass more cases but this is still O(n^2) which is probably why it's not passing all the cases.  If needed I could point you towards an O(n) solution.

Comment: @DarrylG, Ok please give me hint to change algorithm. Thanku

Comment: @Sailaja--since you're close * posted an answer with the code tweak you need to make your software O(n).